# I need to create H and T shaped lines

Tags: vector

I need to join two lines but not by the ends but by the middle or by a middle and the end. I was looking around but I don't find how to do this
Somebody can help me?
Thanks

Comment: It's not possible.  Vectors can't be joined to anchors/nodes in the middle of a path.  Just group the different pieces instead.

Comment: No such thing. You can either group multiple lines, or outline the strokes into actual shapes, in which case you gain some more flexible adjustments, but you lose the stroke-level possible effects.

Answer (score 2):

Bezier Paths - like those in Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape, et. al. - can **not** be joined in the "middle".

- Each Bezier path has anchor points.
- Paths can **only** be connected *at anchor points*
- All anchor points can only contain 2 path connectors, and "in" path and an "out" path.
- No anchor point can contain more than 2 path connections.

**What you are trying to do, can't be done.**

One typically *aligns* the end of a *separate path*, so that it *appears* be connected, but it never actually is. Then it is often helpful to *group* the separate paths, so they can be moved as a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is fundamentally important. Illustrator, and other direct modelling software do not try to take you description and spit out a print ready format. What it does is it makes you covert your internal idea of how things ought to be into illustrators model.

Joining only exists because otherwise it would be impossible to describe concave and hollow shapes. But the system is not interested in why you would want to join a thing in middle. Its only interested in how to draw things. No shape that needs this function exists. Thus they do not implement it. Thus Scott's answer **What you are trying to do, can't be done.**

I do not say that it couldn't be handy, but the system only implements what is absolutely necessary. Handy is not necessary.

Conversely you also do not need this to model a t shape. Consider grouping instead if for some reason selecting with a drag is too cumbersome. There is no problem lines can overlap.